# analysis complex

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that the function $z^n$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, is entire, using the conditions of Cauchy-Riemann. My problem is to calculate the partial derivatives of this function.

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Rather than "whole", the term used in mathematical English is "entire."  Also, the convention is to use $C$ for the set of complex numbers rather than $Z$.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the correction!

Comment: They asked you to show it directly? That's enough to prove it for f(z) = z... If they want you to do the Cauchy-Riemann for this function, then you can try to use the Newton's binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f=u_f + i v_f$ and $g = u_g + i v_g$ are entire functions, then the product $h = fg = u_h + i v_h $ is also entire. We have:

$$
\begin{split}
u_h &= u_f u_g - v_f v_g\\
v_h &= u_f v_g + v_f u_g
\end{split}$$

We can then show that:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u_h}{\partial x} =&u_g  \frac{\partial u_f}{\partial x} +u_f  \frac{\partial u_g}{\partial x} -v_g  \frac{\partial v_f}{\partial x} -v_f  \frac{\partial v_g}{\partial x}\\
 = &u_g  \frac{\partial v_f}{\partial y} +u_f  \frac{\partial v_g}{\partial y} +v_g  \frac{\partial u_f}{\partial y} +v_f  \frac{\partial u_g}{\partial y}\\
=&\frac{\partial v_h}{\partial y} 
\end{split}
$$

and similarly it's easy to demonstrate that the other Cauchy-Riemann relations are satisfied. This then allows you to do induction. The case $n=1$ is trivial and the product rule for the Cauchy-Riemann relations  then allows you to prove the case $n+1$ from assuming that it's valid for $n$ and $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Entire function.

if $f(z) = u + iv$ then $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$

The tricky part is geting $z^n$ in to $u+iv$ form

$z = r(cos\theta +i\sin \theta)\\
z^n = r^n\cos n\theta +ir^n\sin n\theta\\
u= r^n\cos n\theta\\
v=r^n\sin n\theta$

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = nr^{n-1}\cos n\theta \frac {\partial r}{\partial x} - nr^n\sin n\theta \frac {\partial\theta}{\partial x}$

$r = (x^2+y^2)^\frac 12\\
\frac {\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac xr$

$\theta = \arctan \frac yx\\
\frac {\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac y{r^2}$

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = nr^{n-2} (x \cos n\theta  - y\sin n\theta)$

Now use a similar process to find: $\frac {\partial u}{\partial y},\frac {\partial v}{\partial x},\frac {\partial v}{\partial y}$

and show that $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$

Comment: Your idea is pretty elegant, but this is not the formula for the argument. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)

Comment: @IamnotPaulErdos it is a simplification (and is true when $x>0$).   However $\frac {\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac {x}{r^2}$ is still correct regardless of which quadrant you are in.

Comment: Great, that's reasonable.